# What is the relationship between java:comp/env and java:global?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ejb, jndi, conventions, lookup

What is the relationship between `java:comp/env` and `java:global` (regarding 3.1 spec)?
Seems like `java:comp/env` contains specific to EJB references. 
What means "specific" in this case?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`java:global` is a namespace that's global for the entire application server, which includes other EAR modules (which are considered to be different applications).

`java:comp/env` is a *much* smaller namespace. For the web module, it corresponds to all web components (servlets etc) which are all together considered to be a single 'component' for JNDI, but for EJB beans it's a namespace for a single bean, since every bean is considered to be a separate component.

There's also a `java:app` and a `java:module`, whose scopes fall between global and comp.

A big difference between `java:comp/env` and the others is that the former is strictly read-only at runtime and contains among others the beans that are injected into some component. So e.g. consider:

```
@Stateless 
public class ExampleBean {

    @EJB
    OtherBean testBean;

}
```

In this case, the specific proxy that was injected into the field `testBean` can also be obtained from `java:comp/env`, but only when `java:comp/env` is referenced from within ExampleBean (JNDI is highly contextual).

If you however wanted a different proxy to the EJB `OtherBean`, or wanted a reference when no injection had been done, you can get those from any of the other scopes. Depending on from which class you're doing the JNDI call, you would be able to use smaller scopes.

For instance, if `OtherBean` is defined in the same module as `ExampleBean`, you could use `java:module`, if it's the same application (but possibly different modules) you can use `java:app`.

Finally, `java:global` is always safe to use, as it doesn't depend on the context. This means you could use from within e.g. a non-managed completely separate thread. The downside to using `java:global` is that you have to include the application name and the module name if an EAR is used, and otherwise at least the module name.