# JNDI Lookup on JBoss AS 6.0

Tags: jakarta-ee, jndi, jboss6.x

I have an application deployed at localhost on JBoss 6.0 AS. This application has one remote EJB bean called ExampleEJB. Now I'm trying to code a simple client application that consumes ExampleEJB. This client application will not be deployed at any application server. The idea is to code a simple Java SE client program. I've written the following trying to perform a lookup:

```
Properties env = new Properties();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,"org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"localhost:1099");
env.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs","org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");

InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(env);
```

At this point, I've tried two approaches The first one was to perform a direct lookup like examplified at Java EE 6 Tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gipjf.html):

```
ExampleEJB exampleEJB = (ExampleEJB) ic.lookup("java:global/myApp/ExampleEJB");
```

The second attempt was to try to get the JNDI context enviroment and then get the desired bean from this enviroment:

```
Context envContext  = (Context)ic.lookup("java:/comp/env");
envContext.lookup(...)
```

The problem is that I'm receiving the following exceptions: "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: global not bound" and "javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: comp not bound" respectively. I'm unable to perform the lookup as desired.

Does someone have a clue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `java:global/`, then the JNDI name should look like this:

```
java:global/<application>/<module>/<component>
```

or

```
java:global/<ear>/<ejb-jar>/<ejb-name>
```

where *ear* is the name of the .ear file, and *ejb-jar* the name of the EJB .jar file.

---

If you have both a local and a remote interface, you can differ using this scheme:

```
java:global/<ear>/<ejb-jar>/<ejb-name>!<interface>
```

where the *interface* contains the package and the interface name (example: `a.b.c.ExampleEJBRemoteIfc`).

---

So in your setup: If `myApp.ear` contains `myEjb.jar` which contains an EJB whose name is `ExampleEJB`, then try this JNDI name:

```
java:global/myApp/myEjb/ExampleEJB
```

or

```
java:global/myApp/myEjb/ExampleEJB!a.b.c.ExampleEJBRemoteIfc
```

---

Anyway, double check the JNDI name(s) in the JMX console:

```
http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/
```

1. Click *Service=JNDIView*
2. Operation *list*: Click *invoke* button
3. Search in that page by the EJB name

---

As for *comp/env* vs. *global*: [What is the relationship between java:comp/env and java:global](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7458114/2390083)

Comment: Hello, Beryllium. Thank you very much for your answer. I've checked JNDIView at jmx-console. Didn't know about that when I wrote the question. When I performed the lookup at the location: "ExampleEar/ExampleEJBImpl/remote" everything worked fine. Can you confirm me that JBoss binds EJB to locations without the "java:global" prefix? Do you know why? I thought that was the Java EE 6 specification so every application server would respect the default "java:global/<application>/<module>/<component>" location.

Comment: The name is bound to different namespaces (with different scopes). That's why I have started the answer with "if you are using java:global ...". So yes, there are other locations as well with different schemes. The name you have picked works as well. What does JNDIView show in the java: namespace? In my case, the java:global entry is just a link in JNDI to the entry that you have used. So both should work.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I can also see my ExampleEJBImpl on java: namespace like you said. It's on both Global and Java namespaces. However, I'm unable to access the java namespace from my client application. Even if I use the right path that JNDIView gives me. Aparently the problem occurs when I try to perform the lookup from a different JVM process. Java namespace is only accessible from the same JVM. In my case I have to use the global namespace to perform the lookup. Is that right? Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've solved my problem. I've discovered that it is possible to visualize JNDI tree on JBoss by accessing  JBoss JMX Management Console (default location at localhost:8080/jmx-console/). Find JNDIView service and invoke list method. By visualizing the JNDI tree I discovered that I was looking for the wrong location. JBoss registered my EJB at:

```
+- ExampleEar (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   +- ExampleEJBImpl (class: org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContext)
  |   |   +- remote-br.exemplo.ejb.ExampleEJB (class: Proxy for: br.example.ejb.ExampleEJB)
  |   |   +- remote (class: Proxy for: br.example.ejb.ExampleEJB)
```

I just modified my code to perform the lookup at:

```
ExampleEJB exampleEJB = (ExampleEJB) ic.lookup("ExampleEar/ExampleEJBImpl/remote");
```

and everything went fine.