# CORBA lookup for java:comp/env/ or java:global

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, rmi, corba

The CORBA lookup, [EntAppLookup](https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppLookup), works so far as it goes, [better than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26320745/glassfish-appclient-usage-for-a-enterprise-application-client) running the `appclient`.  However, I would at least like to use [standard naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631839/what-is-javacomp-env).  Specifically, `java:comp/env`, [or similar conventions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7458114/262852), to reference the EJB.  Deploying the Enterprise Application, with EJB module, and running the CORBA lookup:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ ll NetBeansProjects/EntAppEJB/dist/EntAppEJB.ear 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 thufir thufir 4659 Oct 11 22:17 NetBeansProjects/EntAppEJB/dist/EntAppEJB.ear
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/asadmin
Use "exit" to exit and "help" for online help.
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-applications
Nothing to list.
No applications are deployed to this target server.
Command list-applications executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> deploy NetBeansProjects/EntAppEJB/dist/EntAppEJB.ear
Application deployed with name EntAppEJB.
Command deploy executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-jndi-entries
UserTransaction: com.sun.enterprise.transaction.startup.TransactionLifecycleService$2
ejb.EJBRemoteInterface__3_x_Internal_RemoteBusinessHome__: javax.naming.Reference
ejb: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
ejb.EJBRemoteInterface: javax.naming.Reference
java:global: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
jdbc: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
concurrent: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
com.sun.enterprise.container.common.spi.util.InjectionManager: com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.util.InjectionManagerImpl
jms: com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.TransientContext
ejb.EJBRemoteInterface#ejb.EJBRemoteInterface: javax.naming.Reference
Command list-jndi-entries executed successfully.
asadmin> 
asadmin> list-jndi-resources
Command list-jndi-resources executed successfully.
asadmin>  
asadmin> exit
Command multimode executed successfully.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/EntAppLookup/dist/EntAppLookup.jar
Oct 11, 2014 10:21:55 PM entapplookup.EntAppLookup main
INFO: This is My Session Bean
thufir@dur:~$
```

glassfish log showing the EAR being deployed:

```
[2014-10-11T22:25:43.750-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS_ACDEPL-00104] [javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient] [tid: _ThreadID=141 _ThreadName=admin-listener(7)] [timeMillis: 1413091543750] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java Web Start services stopped for the app client EntAppEJB/EntAppClient.jar]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:06.364-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091626364] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:06.390-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091626390] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:06.444-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091626444] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:06.724-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00054] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091626724] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Portable JNDI names for EJB MySession: [java:global/EntAppEJB/EntAppEJB-ejb/MySession, java:global/EntAppEJB/EntAppEJB-ejb/MySession!ejb.EJBRemoteInterface]]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:06.724-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-EJB-00055] [javax.enterprise.ejb.container] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091626724] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Glassfish-specific (Non-portable) JNDI names for EJB MySession: [ejb.EJBRemoteInterface#ejb.EJBRemoteInterface, ejb.EJBRemoteInterface]]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:07.529-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091627529] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] public org.glassfish.jms.injection.JMSCDIExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:07.538-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091627538] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] org.glassfish.sse.impl.ServerSentEventCdiExtension.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>, BeanManager) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:07.559-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARN] [] [org.jboss.weld.Event] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091627559] [levelValue: 900] [[
  WELD-000411: Observer method [BackedAnnotatedMethod] private org.glassfish.jersey.gf.cdi.internal.CdiComponentProvider.processAnnotatedType(@Observes ProcessAnnotatedType<Object>) receives events for all annotated types. Consider restricting events using @WithAnnotations or a generic type with bounds.]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:09.402-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [AS-ACDEPL-00112] [javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091629402] [levelValue: 900] [[
  The following extensions or libraries are referenced from the manifest of /home/thufir/glassfish-4.1/glassfish/domains/domain1/applications/EntAppEJB/EntAppClient.jar but were not found where indicated: EJBRemoteInterface.jar ; ignoring and continuing]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:09.434-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-ACDEPL-00103] [javax.enterprise.system.container.appclient] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091629434] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java Web Start services started for the app client EntAppEJB/EntAppClient.jar (contextRoot: /EntAppEJB/EntAppClient)]]

[2014-10-11T22:27:09.554-0700] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=41 _ThreadName=admin-listener(4)] [timeMillis: 1413091629554] [levelValue: 800] [[
  EntAppEJB was successfully deployed in 3,216 milliseconds.]]
```

general documentation entry on github of my progress:

https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppClientJWS

which includes links to the following:

the Enterprise Application and EJB module:
EntAppEJB
https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppEJB

the CLI appclient:
EntAppClient
https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppClient

the remote interface library:
EJBRemoteInterface
https://github.com/THUFIR/EJBRemoteInterface

the CORBA lookup:
EntAppLookup
https://github.com/THUFIR/EntAppLookup

When I try to lookup the EJB with `java:comp/env/` type syntax, I get naming errors:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/EntAppLookup/dist/EntAppLookup.jar
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/ejb.EJBRemoteInterface' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/ejb.EJBRemoteInterface]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at entapplookup.EntAppLookup.main(EntAppLookup.java:17)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/ejb.EJBRemoteInterface
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 3 more
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ glassfish-4.1/glassfish/bin/appclient -client NetBeansProjects/EntAppLookup/dist/EntAppLookup.jar
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/EJBRemoteInterface' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS=pass123, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=localhost, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL=user1} [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/EJBRemoteInterface]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:438)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at entapplookup.EntAppLookup.main(EntAppLookup.java:16)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/EJBRemoteInterface
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:741)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:715)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:159)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:471)
    ... 3 more
thufir@dur:~$
```

How can I deploy the Enterprise Application and look it up with CORBA using conventional `java:comp/env/` type syntax?  Why does this lookup fail when I run it?

Comment: The name you're looking up doesn't agree with the name listed by the tool.

Comment: The lookup `Object obj = ctx.lookup("ejb.EJBRemoteInterface");` does work, even though it doesn't seem like it should.

Comment: So what's your question? You're looking up the wrong name still.

Comment: @EJP I get `Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/EJBRemoteInterface'` and `'java:comp/env/ejb.EJBRemoteInterface'` as well.

Comment: Not surprising. Neither of those is the name it is bound by. Look at the `asadmin` tool output.

Comment: ...which BTW is `ejb.EJBRemoteInterface#ejb.EJBRemoteInterface`, not any of the strings you've used so far.

Comment: 'asadmin' shows 'ejb.EJBRemoteInterface: javax.naming.Reference'; why is `ejb.EJBRemoteInterface#ejb.EJBRemoteInterface` preferable?  The first one **works** -- although I'd rather use `java:comp..` or similar.